# My ASP.NET Core's ApiController is not functional - JS Fetch returns 404

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, configuration, recaptcha-v3, asp.net-core-6.0

So I have my endpoint defined like the following:

```
[ApiController]
    [Route("load/stuff")]
    public class SignUp : ControllerBase
    {
        IGoogleRecaptchaV3Service _gService { get; set; }
        public SignUp(IGoogleRecaptchaV3Service gService)
        {
            _gService = gService;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromQuery] SignUpModel SignUpData, GRequestModel.Factory grequestFactory)
        {

            GRequestModel grm = grequestFactory("resValue", "remipValue");

            _gService.InitializeRequest(grm);

            if (!await _gService.Execute())
            {
                //return error codes string.
                return Ok(_gService.Response.error_codes);
            }

            //call Business layer
           
            return base.Content("Content here", "text/html");
        }
    }
```

This should return the HTML content if the reCAPTCHA score is human-like.
Let me know how to debug this further and whether any further code is required.

**UPDATE fetch JS Code**

```
function loadStuff() {
    if (location.pathname === "/test") {
        grecaptcha.execute('recaptchasitekeyhere', { action: 'onloadafterdelay' }).then(function (token) {
            console.log(token);
            return fetch("/load/stuff?RecaptchaToken=" + token, {
                method: "POST",
                body: token,
            })
        }).then((response) => {
            // console.log works here too
            if (!response.ok) {
                const errorBuild = {
                    type: "Error",
                    message: response.message || "Something went wrong",
                    data: response.data || "",
                    code: response.code || "",
                };
                console.log("Error: " + JSON.stringify(errorBuild));
            }
            response.text().then(body => {
                //console.log(body);
                document.getElementById("test1").innerHTML = body.split('  ')[0];
                document.getElementById("test2").innerHTML = body.split('  ')[1];
            });
        }
        )
    }
}
```

I also added this in the program.cs file:

```
builder.Services.AddControllers();
// FIX TEST
builder.Services.AddTransient<GRequestModel.Factory>(serviceProvider =>
     (string res, string remip) => new GRequestModel(serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>(), res, remip));
//Register dependencies
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
// REMOVE ME IN PRODUCTION, USE DI INSTEAD
// ....

Configuration = app.Configuration;
// ...

public partial class Program
{
    internal static IConfiguration Configuration { get; private set; }
}
```

I added that code above as a temporary fix, but then I tried to implement dependency injection for the IConfiguration and my codebase got dirty. I'm still a beginner in C# and I'm learning by trial and error hence so many mistakes.

Comment: Please show your JSFetch code.

Comment: make sure you registered your routing services and added it to request pipeline, after that the endpoint should be accessible at [POST]/load/stuff (depending on the routing configuration), double check that you are sending correct HTTP method from JS, the code snippet seems ok to me..

Comment: also, is there some reason behind sending the SignUpModel in query params? why not use body?

Comment: One more thing, I would consider using action filters for implementing recaptcha validation

Comment: @Llama added the code in the question

Comment: @Sonyck I added that, I'm adding it to the question as well just to be sure that I did it wirght. Are Action Filters supported in ASP.NET Core 6 even?

Comment: Hi, 404 means your request url cannot be found. But from your apicontroller, the request url is correct. I say your `then` function's comment:`console.log works here too`.  So where did you makes 404 error. Could you please share more details?

Comment: @Rena that's the thing - the endpoint should be exposed and as you've mentioned the URL seems to be correct... What else should I share?

Comment: The main issue is that something is probably wrong with my endpoint and I have no clue how to debug that..

Comment: Hi, 1) are client code run on same site 2) do you add `app.MapControllers();` in program.cs file

Comment: @Rena 1) what do you mean by client code in this case? 2) yes, I do

Comment: I mean, are your js code and api code in the same application?

Comment: @Rena Yes, they are.

Comment: @Munchkin, If so, could you please share your whole program.cs?

Comment: @Rena I apparently had to rollback the program.cs to the old version (.NET 5) due to the fact that I was unable to find a solution in the right time...